# Do we use singular verb for uncommon unit?

Tags: grammaticality

A rule from a book stated "Use a singular verb with distances, periods of time, sums of money, etc., when considered as a unit."

While this book use common unit as an example such as "miles, years,...", I was wondering if it apply to uncommon unit like apples, bananas, etc, too. I tried to find my answer on the internet and most source only use common unit.

Examples:
10 apples **is** the maximum amount that a child can eat.
OR 
10 apples **are** the maximum amount that a child can eat.

techniqually, apples here is a **unit** of how much apple there are.

Where I get the rule from: 
Straus, J., Stern, T., Kaufman, L., & Wiley, J. (2021). *The blue book of grammar and punctuation : an easy-to-use guide with clear rules, real-world examples, and reproducible quizzes.* (12th ed.) Jossey-Bass A Wiley Brand. on page7.

‌

Comment: I would indeed say "is".

Comment: I doubt things like apples are units as that term is usually used: apples are not fungible whereas, in principle at least, grams are. I cannot cite an authority, but neither the singular nor plural verb sounds ungrammatical to me. If apples are considered items, plural is fine. If some “standard” apple is considered a unit of appleness, then the unit rule suggests a singular verb as in “250 kilograms of sugar is a lethal overdose.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*10 apples **is** the maximum amount that a child can eat*" is correct.

It's correct because the *subject complement* is "the maximum amount", which is singular. This means that although 10 apples represents more than one of something, its function in this sentence is *a single amount*, so it's singular.

The rules you read in books that say to use singular verbs with units of measure are correct, but there's no special rule about units of measure. The rule is simply that if a noun phrase with more than one unit in it functions as a single amount, then it's singular, no matter what what the unit is.

THAT SAID, you will also see, "10 apples **are** the maximum amount that a child can eat", but it's less common, and some consider it wrong.